# create db from share from different role in reader account Snowflake

Tags: database, permissions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-grant

I have a `share`(i.e. shareTest_share) in `accountAdmin` role in one of my reader accounts in snowflake.

Now I want to create a database from this, but from `sysAdmin` role.

The statement for creating database is:

```
CREATE or replace DATABASE shareTest_db FROM SHARE mukulanalytics.shareTest_share
```

This is giving permission issue since I am trying to execute it from the `sysAdmin` role instead of `accountAdmin` role which has the access to `shareTest_share` share.

**Error:**

```
SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on foreign share 'SHARETEST_SHARE'
```

How can I create a database from share in a different role with share in another role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to grant the IMPORT SHARE privilege to SYSADMIN/any other users

use role accountadmin

grant import share on account to sysadmin

use role sysadmin

create database TEST from share <>

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-privileges-shares.html

Answer (score 1):

the privileges required to achieve this are described here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-privileges-shares.html